# N users must approve a request

Tags: public-key, signature, authentication

I have a locked-down production system that we'd like to process specific requests, picked-up (poll) from a less-secure location.  For security and "go slow, this is production" reasons, a request must be authorized by 2 (or N) people on the team.

I can imagine how to implement this fairly simply just using openssl and signatures -- e.g., the secure server has a pool of public keys (people on the team who can authorize a request) and any submitted request must be correctly signed (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782826/digital-signature-for-a-file-using-openssl) with the private keys of N different people from that pool.

But it seems like a common-enough requirement that it must already exist; any pointers?  I have a suspicion I'm just not searching for the right terminology...  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is called [$(t,n)$-threshold signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_cryptosystem), where you need at least $t$ parties (out of a total of $n$) to create a signature. Considering your description, it seems that in your case $t=n$, so it is necessary that all the keys are used for creating the signature.

This answer assumes that you want to verify the signature with a single public key (i.e., $n$ signatures, 1 verification). If you want to use $n$ public keys, then you can just require $n$ independent signatures.

Comment: Ah interesting -- I wasn't aware there's a way to support this without even maintaining a list of accepted signers to check with.  In our case we're not t=n, actually (any two people out of a larger team should be able to sign a request to make it authentic), but the idea applies.  Because we already have our own public keys, it may in the end be simpler to simply require n independent signatures.  I still don't see implementations around that do this, but it's a simple enough case that perhaps most people are using custom setups anyway.